# Overzealous Moderation - Thread wrongly put on hold

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

https://serverfault.com/questions/820124/how-can-i-get-access-to-a-new-version-of-mysqldump-on-a-server-that-is-out-of-da

[image: Hold Message]

My question appears to me to be:

1. Concerning information technology systems
2. In a business environment
3. Not regarding home and end-user computer questions
4. Not about Development, testing, or development tools.

Comment: For future references, most people here are professional sysadmins. And the administrators and regulars almost all are. So saying `I asked my sysadmin to do it, and got generic non-helpful responses.` Is maybe not the best way to state what steps you did to resolve your problem. Also EEAA was hardly overzealous here, in the function of your question you are an end-user of the mysql server, not its administrator. And he gave you an answer in the comments.

Comment: An issue that is commonly perceived on the stack exchange sites is overzealous moderation. I run into that feeling too.  

I agree that EEAA was not overzealous given the rules. I also think he did a really bad job of explaining them to me. He took the time to post an explanation (or the software did) but that explanation did not match my post.

Imagine you were stopped from entering a theater. When you're turned away, the usher says "Only people with tickets and no hats are allowed in." You look down, you have a ticket, and you're not wearing a hat. How would you feel?

Comment: If he had said instead "You need full control of your system for this exchange." I would have thanked him, apologized for posting in the wrong place, and felt good about the transaction. (Like I did once Sven pointed out the appropriate rule). 

Communication is important.

Comment: Yes, but he tried to answer you even if its offtopic. In the final atleast he commented, as even I stopped to comment on closed question as most of the time, unlike you, a lot of user take it personnal and start hating comment after a comment. Its good to help someone that take it like you, but we walk on egg when we comment a closed question. My point is, atleast he commented, and even tried to answer you, as such a comment of like ´we cant help' as you are not the admin, can start something bad

Comment: @JoshuaD My Point was not to defend EEAA. My Point was that you probably made a bit first impression. By starting of with a sentence that implies you don't believe the sysadmins who maintains the server's opinion is worth considering. While asking for help in a Q&A full of sysadmins. How would you like it if a moviegoer with no pants on walked up to you (an usher) in the cinema and went "your colleague won't let me in because of some stupid rule, how can I sneak in?".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One very important requirement for questions on ServerFault: You need to be administrator on the system in question, in order to be able to fully follow possible answers. That rules you out, at least in the context of this question.

The question might fit on other sites in the SE network.

Comment: What Sven said.  Check the topicality rules on dba.stackexchange.com;  your question might fit in there.